# How to use bandwidth matrix from R in Kernel Density tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5, kernel-density

I want to calculate and map kernel densities using ArcGIS (10.5 so I am unable to use GME). I calculated a bandwidth matrix using the plugin method in the ks package in R. How can I input and use that in the kernel density ArcMap tool?

Comment: There is no way to pass a custom kernel function to the ArcGIS kernel density tool. Please take a look at the syntax of the tool, it is quite apparent that there is no option for specifying your own kernel. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/kernel-density.htm

Comment: I was able to manually enter a search radius in the tool so it seems there is a way to specify the bandwidth. I'm just not sure how my calculated bandwidth from R should be entered.

Comment: I thought that you wanted the kernel weights. You can specify bandwidth but not the nxn bandwidth matrix that ks returns. Perhapse you should keep this analysis in R.